# Display figures and names with tooltips and mark_text with Altair

Tags: python-3.x, tooltip, geopandas, altair

Here are three issues I have with tooltips and labels that I want to display on my Altair graph. All the issues are more or less linked.

1. First, I would like to modify the name of the information I display with the tooltip:

*Year* instead of *properties.annee*

*Region* instead of *properties.region*

*Bioenergy* instead of *properties.bioenerie...*

2. Second, I would like to round the values displayed in the tooltip.
   "11.2" instead of "11.1687087653"
   The code I wrote does what I want for the labels I put in the regions but it is not working for the tooltip.
3. Third, I would like to display the unit in the labels and in the tooltip but I don't find  the correct syntax in the documentation.

Below is my code.

Thanks in advance for yous answers.

Bertrand

[Current result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOggn.png)

```
    def gen_map(data: gpd.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame, title: str, abs_values: bool):    
        data_json = json.loads(data.to_json())
        choro_data = alt.Data(values=data_json['features'])

        # Absolute values or relative values
        if abs_values:
            column = data.columns[0]
            units = 'MW'
            form = '.0f'
        else:
            column = data.columns[1]
            units = '%'
            form = '.1f'

        # Base layer
        layer = alt.Chart(choro_data, title=title).mark_geoshape(
            stroke='white',
            strokeWidth=1
        ).encode(
            alt.Color(f'properties.{column}:Q',
                   type='quantitative',
                   title = f'Installed Capacity in {units}'),
        tooltip=[f'properties.annee:Q', 
                 f'properties.region:O', 
                 f'properties.{column}:Q', 
                 alt.Text(f'properties.{column}:Q', format=form)]
         ).transform_lookup(
            lookup='region',
            from_=alt.LookupData(choro_data, 'region')
        ).properties(
            width=600,
            height=500
        )

        # Label layer
        labels = alt.Chart(choro_data).mark_text(baseline='top'
                                             ).properties(
            width=600,
            height=500
        ).encode(
            longitude='properties.centroid_lon:Q',
            latitude='properties.centroid_lat:Q',
            text=alt.Text(f'properties.{column}:Q', format=form),
            size=alt.value(14),
            opacity=alt.value(1)        
        )

        return layer + labels

    gen_map(bioenergies_2019, 'Bioenergy in France in 2019', False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a list of strings, use a list of [`alt.Tooltip`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/channels/altair.Tooltip.html) objects:

```
tooltip=[alt.Tooltip('properties.annee:Q', title='Annee'),
         alt.Tooltip('properties.region:O', title='Region'),
         alt.Tooltip(f'properties.{column}:Q', title=f'{column}')]
```

You can additionally pass the `format` argument to specify the format of the value; for number formats, use [d3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#locale_format) codes; for date/time formats use [d3-date-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format) codes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped me.

I have one more question: how would it be possible to code a new format so that my figure would be displayed with personalized units, for instance 250MW. 
How can I add a new personnalize format ?
thank you.